# Why won't my lines move?

Tags: c++

Okay, so I'm calling a function that draws three lines to display an 'I' on-screen.
Then, I call another function which calls this function, but adds 1 to the x variable to
make a the letter bold. Then I want to put x++ add in the 'tick' function, which executes
every frame. It isn't working, but why? If you don't understand what I mean, please check this page, it's the tutorial I'm following: http://www.devmaster.net/articles/intro-to-c++-with-game-dev/part3.php

Declare global x and y and call function tick:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
void Game::Tick( float a_DT )
{
    m_Screen->Clear( 80 );
    DrawI(0,0);
    x++;
}
```

Making functions:

```
void Game::DrawI(int x, int y)
{
    m_Screen->Line( 100 + x, 50 + y, 200 + x, 50 + y, 0xffffff );
    m_Screen->Line( 150 + x, 50 + y, 150 + x, 300 + y, 0xffffff );
    m_Screen->Line( 100 + x, 300 + y, 200 + x, 300 + y, 0xffffff );
}

void Game::DrawFatI()
{
    DrawI(1,0);
    DrawI(0,1);
    DrawI(0,0);
    DrawI(1,1);
}
```

Thanks for checking.

Comment: You're missing the `+ x` and `+ y` parts

Comment: Your `DrawI()` function makes no use at all of the arguments. What did you *expect* would happen? Did you compile with all warnings and pay attention?

Comment: Just a comment: using the same names "x" and "y" for both global and local variables/function parameters is going to cause you a lot of headache.

Comment: `Tick` increments the global variable `x`, while `DrawI` uses a local variable `x`. They are completely unconnected. Instead, `Tick` should call `DrawI(x,0)`.

Comment: Guys, I made a mistake with copying the code. Please check my edited post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call DrawI it has `x` and `y` passed to it as parameters:

```
void Game::DrawI(int x, int y)
```

These *mask* the global `x` and `y`, such that within `DrawI` everywhere you say `x` and `y` it refers to the function parameters. (You can access the global ones using `::x` and `::y` though).

Since you always call `DrawI` with literals, not variables, e.g. `DrawI(1,0);` the values of `x` and `y` in `DrawI` never change, they are always just these fixed values and not the global variable, hence `Line` is always passed the same values, even if your global `x` has changed.

I would make two recommendations to avoid this:

1. Don't have multiple variables with the same name where one masks the other
2. Don't use globals, unless there's a *good* reason to. (This doesn't seem to be one as far as I can see)

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. :)